# Why do mathematicians study elementary abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I took two algebra courses that I liked as an undergraduate mathematics major in college, but we never covered elementary abelian groups.  I recently got interested in the properties of a group I encountered, and after some research I realized that the group I was interested in is isomorphic to an elementary abelian group.

Are there many interesting properties of these groups?  What makes elementary abelian groups worth studying?  (I have glanced at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group), but did not immediately see why mathematicians care about these groups.)

Any insights or even scholarly papers would be appreciated--thanks.

Comment: An elementary $p$-group is a vector space over the field with $p$ elements. So they're not really very interesting groups by themselves. But the fact that one can use linear algebra with them often makes for short arguments.

Comment: "Two solid algebra course"...and you didn't study elementary abelian groups, which is part of basic group theory?!That doesn't sound  very solid to me. Anyway, elementary abelian groups are direct products of several copies (even infinite) of  $\;\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$  ,for some prime $\;p\;$, and they have a pretty simple, even natural, structure of vector spaces over the prime field $\;\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$

Comment: I don't think elementary abelian groups are interesting in their own right (except if you want to go in the vector space direction), but in situations where groups arise we can sometimes study those situations which give arise specifically to elementary abelian groups - as an initial case study with tame ecomplexity, say. (E.g. as Galois groups or subfactors of another group.) @Timbuc Perhaps OP means they did not specifically highlight elementary abelian groups when covering structure theory of finite abelian groups.

Comment: Well, by solid I meant that I was satisfied with them, and they were some of the strongest courses in the department (it wasn't MIT...).  It is *possible* that we studied them and I forgot...it was at least 6 years ago and I haven't done much algebra since.  What is the linear algebra you can do with them?

Comment: @anon Basic group theory,as far as I know,  usually covers finite abelian groups, and/or even finitely generated abelian groups and the Fundamental Theorem on this. Elementary abelian groups usually appear very naturally there, but of course: I could be wrong and in many parts they teach that stuff differently.

Comment: @PhilipWhite For example, for finite elementary abelian groups, their automorphism  group is pretty simple to visualize and even calculate its order, and also subgroups are in one-to-one correspondence with vector subspaces, so it is easier to calculate their number.

Comment: @Timbuc, yes, but just studying finite abelian groups in the abstract does not mean elementary abelian ones were picked out specifically and highlighted with a focus, any more than studying finite groups in the abstract means one studied groups of squarefree order as a special focus (did you know we have an explicit formula for the # of groups with any given sqrfree order? that doesn't make it into textbooks). | OP, pretty much any linear algebra you can do with an infinite vector space you can do with a finite one. Except you can't divide by the characteristic of the scalar field.